# Retornar apenas um atributo de um objeto?

Tags: javascript, array, objetos, filter

Gostaria de saber como obter apenas um atributo de um objeto ...

```
const person = [
  { name: 'Jane', age: 55 },
  { name: 'Rafael', age: 23 },
  { name: 'Carolina', age: 19 },
  { name: 'Bob', age: 47 },
  { name: 'Julia', age: 62 },
  { name: 'Joy', age: 43 }
];

const biggestNames = person.filter(person => person.name.length >= 5);
console.log(biggestNames);
```

Assim desta forma, me retornara os obj's com os maiores nomes de acordo com o argumento que foi passado `(person.name.length >= 5)`, porém gostaria que ele retornasse apenas o valor do atributo name do meu obj, e não o obj completo `({ name: x, age: x })` em sí...

Agradeço ...

Answer (score 5):

Assim como o método `filter` também existe um método chamado `map` que você pode invocar num array para gerar um novo array. Nesse caso, o `map` produz um array com o valor retornado da sua callback, então bastaria retornar o nome da pessoa nessa callback:

```js
const persons = [
  { name: 'Jane', age: 55 },
  { name: 'Rafael', age: 23 },
  { name: 'Carolina', age: 19 },
  { name: 'Bob', age: 47 },
  { name: 'Julia', age: 62 },
  { name: 'Joy', age: 43 }
];

const biggestNames = persons
  .filter(person => person.name.length >= 5)
  .map(person => person.name);
  
console.log(biggestNames);
```